# CiviCRM REST API Call

Tags: contacts, api, rest

I'm new to CiviCRM and REST API Calls. I'm attempting to create a new contact using POST via Postman. I'm submitting the following:

```
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=create&api_key=(myAPIkey)&key=(mySiteKey)&json:{“contact_type":"Individual","first_name":"Tester","last_name":"Yolanda"}
```

But I get the response back:

```
     <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
<b>/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php</b> on line
<b>167</b>
<br />
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ResultSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
      </ResultSet>
```

I glanced at line 167 - it seems to be about constructing the response. I know I'm getting some kind of connection - If I change a character in the site or API key, I get "failed to authenticate" - so that part seems to be working.

CiviCRM version 4.7.27, Wordpress version 4.9.1

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Hi SteadH. The ':' after the json argument,  Is it a typo? it should be a '='.

Comment: Thanks! It does seem to be. I started with the correct syntax but when I received a JSON error back even though it was valid, I started experimenting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As kainuk mentioned, you don't have the right syntax for the json field, i needs to be json= instead of json:

```
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=create&api_key=(myAPIkey)&key=(mySiteKey)&json={“contact_type":"Individual","first_name":"Tester","last_name":"Yolanda"}
```

(it needs to be post, not get for all operations like create that modify the database)

and I would strongly recommend you to do rest over an encrypted connection (https instead of http), otherwise you risk having your keys being read by someone else than civi

X+

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same but not with Postman but with a different application outside civicrm - I managed to create a contact without any error message

so, Please try as below this should work

> http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=create&api_key=(myAPIkey)&key=(mySiteKey)&json=1&contact_type='Individual'&first_name='Tester'&last_name='Yolanda'

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: What other program and parameters did you use?

Comment: I am trying to access this link from VB.NET web_request which worked alright also I did tried using POSTMAN too